# How to use [src] in non-Angular elements?

Tags: angular, aframe

I am using [A-Frame](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe) in Angular 2.

When I put image link directly in `src`,

```
<a-scene>
  <a-curvedimage src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg" position="0 2 0"></a-curvedimage>
</a-scene>
```

it works well. [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DaaWUC7DkrOf2HlOOgU0?p=preview)

However, if I am using

```
  <a-scene>
    <a-curvedimage [src]="url" position="0 2 0"></a-curvedimage>
  </a-scene>
```

with

```
  url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg';
```

It won't give me any error, but it also does not show the image. [issue plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oSa9KzMihnmYjEg8xL4Z?p=preview).

How can I solve this issue or any walkaround way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what properties the `a-curvedimage` element has at runtime but it might be the case that it doesn't have the `src` *property* that would reflect value of the `src` *attribute*. In this case your best option might be binding to the `src` *attribute* like so: `<a-curvedimage [attr.src]="url" position="0 2 0"></a-curvedimage>`

Keep in mind that elements rendered in a browser can have both attributes and properties and Angular distinguishes bindings to those. Most of the time an attribute and the corresponding property names are the same so the difference doesn't matter. Still, there are elements where attributes and property names don't match so you need to be precise in your Angular binding syntax.